# interior point method defined in Mathworld

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am studying the interior point method. However, I cannot see the whole picture so far.

As explained in the Mathworld:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InteriorPointMethod.html

> An interior point method is a linear or nonlinear programming method (Forsgren et al. 2002) that achieves optimization by going through the middle of the solid defined by the problem **rather than around its surface**.

I think the interior points here means the interior of the set of feasible region (for example: the interior of the polyhedral defined by the linear programming's inequality constraints.)

I have a few questions however:

1. What does it mean "around its surface?"
2. Which method or algorithm going around the surface (hope for example, such as Newton's algorithm, ADMM....)?

Comment: Until the advent of interior point methods, the simplex method was very dominant for solving LPs, and the simplex method examines vertices of the feasible set (not "interior points").